# Cockroach-like insect identification (India)

Tags: zoology, species-identification, entomology, nomenclature

I just saw an insect in my room, and I have never seen anything like it ever before. I captured a photo, please see if you can identify it. It has got quite unique colours on its exodermis and it has 2 pairs of wings ( I was not able to get a picture of them) which are very similar in structure and position to those of a cockroach. In addition to that, it is able to fly, albeit for short distances.

I live in Kolkata, India and the length of the insect is approx. 6-8 cm.
[image: Insect 1]
[image: insect 2]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a longhorn beetle (*Cerambycidae*).

Most likely, it's a **Red-spotted longhorn beetle (*Batocera rufomaculata*)**, also known as a mango tree borer, mango stem-borer and tropical fig borer.

See this [SE question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/36985/insect-identification-white-spotted-beetle) pertaining to the same insect.

[image: Batocera rufomaculata]

From [Biolib](http://www.biolib.cz/en/taxon/id244539/):

> **Country check-list:** China, India, Israel, Jordan, Laos, Lebanon, Madagascar, Malaysia, Mauritius, Myanmar, Pakistan, Puerto Rico, Sri Lanka, Syria, Thailand, Virgin Islands  [Might Not be complete]
>
> **Food**: *Ficus carica L.* (Fig), *Carica papaya L.* (Papaya), *Mangifera indica L.* (Mango), *Shorea robusta Gaertner f.* (Sal Tree)

It might also be [*B. parryi*](http://www.cerambycoidea.com/foto.asp?Id=157), which, similar to *B. rufomaculata*, is common in [SE Asia](http://www.biolib.cz/en/taxon/id253372/) (but which is absent from Western Asia or Africa where *B. rufomaculata* is also found). Since you live in India, both are possible. I will look for a key to determine how to differentiate the 2 species.

Meanwhile, [here is a list](https://apps2.cdfa.ca.gov/publicApps/plant/bycidDB/wbycidview.asp?tribe=Batocerini&w=o)  of related species in the *Lamiinae* subfamily for further reference.

Also, a great [resource](http://wbbresource.org/default.asp?action=taxonomic&id=Cerambycidae) (including [keys](http://cerambycids.com/longicornid/default.asp?a=tools&id=keys)) for wood boring beetles of the world!

Comment: Thanks, it is the same species atleast morphologically. Just like the one in the answer link you provided.

Comment: Country Checklist: Add Bangladesh